# How do I write to a file and then copy its contents to another file?

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write to a .txt file and then copy it into a second .txt file.

```
from sys import argv

script, send_file, get_file = argv

in_file = open(send_file, "r+")
in_file.write("I'm sending information to the receiver file.")

open(get_file, "w")
get_file.write(f"{in_file}")
```

But I keep getting the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex15_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    get_file.write(f"{in_file}")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Then I put `open(get_file, "w")` and `get_file.write(f"{in_file}")` inside of a variable and get no error whatsoever.

```
out_file = open(get_file, "w")
out_file.write(f"{in_file}")
```

But then this is what ends up being written into the second file:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='sender.txt' mode='r+' encoding='cp1252'>
```

- Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
- Why did it work when I used the variables in the second code?

Comment: open(get_file, "w") will not store your variable anywhere.
out_file = open(get_file, "w") will open and store your file in the variable out_file. That is correct.
Now convert what you want to write into that file to a string and then write. You are currently trying to write a file object into the file, which is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, now it is pretty clear why you need that variable when opening a file, really had the doubt as to why that was nessesary. Thank you so much for your explanation <3.

Answer (score 2):

In `open(get_file, "w")`, `get_file` is the name of the file, it's a string.

You need to write to a file object, as you did to read in the first part of the code. So, it would be:

```
f = open(get_file, "w")
f.write(f"{in_file}")
f.close()
```

Note that you forgot to close both of your files in your code.

The good practice, though, is to use a context manager that will take care of the closing for you, whatever happens in your code (exception, ...)

So, the best way to do it would be:

```
with open(get_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(f"{in_file}")
```

Comment: Oh, I see, so the place where the file will be stored in my code is called a file object. That concept is pretty clear now, I really appreciate it <3

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for messy code but this should do what you want i think

```
from sys import argv

script, send_file, get_file = argv

in_file = open(send_file, "r+")
in_file.write("I'm sending information to the receiver file.")
in_file.close()

in_file_2 = open(send_file, "r")
in_file_text = in_file_2.read()
in_file_2.close()

secondFile = open(get_file, "w")
secondFile.write(f"{in_file_text}")
secondFile.close()
```

Comment: Oh god, this was exactly what I wanted to do. I knew I needed to close the files when I was done with them by the end of the code, but I didn't think of using the close function in that way. Thanks <3

Comment: yes, any changes made to files are only applied after closing the file